# Unexpected Logout in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I don't know the reason of it. I guess the reason could be application's load on CPU But when I try to work on  3 to 4 apps on ubuntu 14.04 it suddenly takes to me on login screen in between on my working state and it lose all of my work. I probably uses qt creator vlc player and a web browser and suddenly its logout. that's so annoying please help me to solve it. I'm using sony vaio with 2.53ghz x 4 i3 processor with 2GB Ram.

Comment: You should run an indicator like `indicator-multiload` and let it display you the current RAM and SWAP usage. I suspect that you run out of memory and therefore the kernel emergency-kills processes to free some space. You can also use the `free -h` command in a terminal repetitiously or `top` to monitor the resource usage.

Comment: Thank you for reply Byte Commander. Can you suggest me any solution these solutions are not much certain and here is the details comes after applying free -h command. mike@mike-VPCEB42EG:~$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1.7G       1.6G        65M       243M        46M       746M
-/+ buffers/cache:       872M       858M
Swap:         1.7G        69M       1.7G

Comment: That `free -h` command just shows the memory usage in the very moment. You need to run that continuously and repeat until the system crashes again, remembering the last output. Important numbers are in row `-/+ buffers/cache:` the column `free:` (amount of RAM available for your programs) and in row `Swap:` the column `free:` (amount of unused swap space). Keep an eye those two figures while executing the command every few seconds and running the applications that usually lead to the crash. If they both become almost zero, you know the problem and must add more RAM or swap.